# HttpModule in subapplication Could not load type

Tags: .net, dll, gac, httpmodule

I am having some problems configurating my httpModule.
The structure of my site is 1 main website with sapperate web applications in it. So I convert my application folders to a web application so his own bin will be used for the code.
In the web.config of my main site I configured a HttpModule connected to the dll in the bin folder of my main website.
Now I am having the problem when converting my sub folders to a real application that I get the error "Could not load type ...". The reason for this is that the dll is situated at a higher level.
First I hoped IIS would check the bin of the web application and if the dll isn't there go further to the bin at a higher level but that is not working.
I have also the problem that for security reasons I cannot deploy my dll to the GAC.
Can somebody give me another solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with some people I discovered the only way to get this thing working is by deploying to the GAC. No other possible answer.